# How to evaluate $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\ln\left(1+e^{x}\right)\mathrm{d}x\textbf{ efficiently}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

I am struggling in evaluating the follow integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\ln\left(1+e^{x}\right)\mathrm{d}x\overset{\text{Wolfram}}{\approx} 2.02049$$
$\color{red}{\text{Despite asking Wolfram to give me 10 digits, it always gives me this result}}$

### My process

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\ln\left(1+e^{x}\right)\mathrm{d}x=1+2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\ln\left(1+e^{-x}\right)\mathrm{d}x$$

> $$\displaystyle\ln(1+x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}x^n\qquad \text{for }|x|<1$$

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\ln\left(1+e^{x}\right)\mathrm{d}x=&1-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}e^{-nx}\mathrm{d}x\\
=&1-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{\frac{n^{2}}{2}}\text{erfc}\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\\
=&1-\sqrt{2\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n}e^{\frac{n^{2}}{2}}\text{erfc}\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\end{align}$$

This solution is correct, but has an huge defect: *it is extremely inefficient to calculate*

When I calculate the series for the first $n$ terms I have to take $e^{\frac{n^2}{2}}$ into account

- $n=10$: $e^{\frac{n^2}{2}}\approx 5.18\cdot 10^{21}$ and the series is $\approx \color{blue}{2.0}115$
- $n=20$: $e^{\frac{n^2}{2}}\approx 7.22\cdot 10^{86}$ and the series is $\approx \color{blue}{2.0}181$
- $n=30$: $e^{\frac{n^2}{2}}\approx 2.70\cdot 10^{195}$ and the series is $\approx \color{blue}{2.0}194$
- $n=50$: $e^{\frac{n^2}{2}}\approx \color{red}{7.38\cdot 10^{542}}$ and the series is $\approx \color{blue}{2.020}0$
- $n=110$: $e^{\frac{n^2}{2}}\approx \color{red}{3.03\cdot 10^{2627}}$ and the series is $\approx \color{blue}{2.0204}$

> In reality these $n$ are even higher because the series is alternated, with $n+1$ they lose a correct figure and with $n+2$ they recover it.

So to calculate at least $3$ correct decimal digits we need to calculate a number that not even Matlab and Desmos are able to handle (the first Desmos and Matlab overflow number is $2^{1024}\approx 1.79\cdot 10^{308}$)

---

### Question

Anyone knows some tricks to solve it in some other way?

> **Hint 1**
> The Taylor series of $\ln(1+e^{-x})$ **cannot** be used, since it has convergence radius $\pi$:
> $$\ln\left(1+e^{-x}\right)=\ln(2)-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{E_{2n-1}(0)}{n(2n-1)!}x^{2n}\qquad |x|<\pi$$
> Therefore used in the integral for $|x|>\pi$ we have that the integral diverges.
>
> - $E_{\nu}(z)$ is the Euler polynomials.

> **Hint 2**
> (It's not useful but it's an interesting thing in my opinion)
> [image]
> $$\text{erfc}(z)e^{z^2}\propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{\left(2n\right)!}{n!}\left(2z\right)^{-2n}$$

> **Hint 3**
> I tried even doing the Gaussian series:
> $$e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{2n}}{2^{n}n!}\qquad \text{for }x\in\mathbb{R}$$
> $$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\ln\left(1+e^{x}\right)dx=&1+2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\ln\left(1+e^{-x}\right)dx\\
> =&1+2\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{2n}}{2^{n}n!}\ln\left(1+e^{-x}\right)dx\\
> =&1+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{2^{n}n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2n}\ln\left(1+e^{-x}\right)dx\\
> \end{align}$$
> $$\color{green}{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{2n}\ln\left(1+e^{-x}\right)dx=\left(1-2^{-2n-1}\right)\zeta\left(2+2n\right)\left(2n\right)!}$$
> $$1+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{2^{n}n!}\left(1-2^{-2n-1}\right)\zeta\left(2+2n\right)\left(2n\right)!$$
> There must be a mistake here because you end up with a $\color{red}{\text{diverget series}}$

> **Hint 4**
> I would like to try the [Gauss–Hermite quadrature formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Hermite_quadrature) but it seems quite complicated to implement (I guess the result comes, but I don't know how quickly)

Comment: change variable with the logarithm

Comment: Hint. Split the integral over the domain in two: over the negative domain and over the positive one. In the negative domain, you do have that $e^x<1.$ For the positive domain, factor out $e^x$ from the logarithm, to make -- in your words -- the argument of the logarithm "finite".

Comment: Rewrite the logarithm’s argument as $e^x\cdot (1 + e^{-x})$, then expand $\log(1 + e^{-x})$ in powers of $e^{-x}$ for the $x>0$ case, etc.

Comment: @Aruralreader I tried it, now I have a series with erfc(z) function ahaha

Comment: Wolfram can give [more than 10 digits](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=NumberForm%5BNIntegrate%5Be%5E%28-x%5E2%2F2%29+ln%28e%5Ex%2B1%29%2C%7Bx%2C-infty%2Cinfty%7D%5D%2C20%5D)

Comment: @ТymaGaidash Ah ok, I had written it another way and it didn't give me any further decimal digits: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+from+-infty+to+infty+e%5E%28-x%5E2%2F2%29ln%281%2Be%5Ex%29dx%2C+10+digits

Comment: @ТymaGaidash However, at most it gives me $15$ decimal digits, even using your syntax (even in yours, it says $20$ digits, but after the decimal point there are only $15$)

Comment: Mathematica can go to more digits of precision using `NIntegrate` and `WorkingPrecision`, e.g., `NIntegrate[Exp[-x^2/2] Log[1 + E^x], {x, -Infinity,Infinity}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]` gives 2.0204907400046658800.

Comment: How about using https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.9 ?

Comment: I think you should read [Guidelines for good use of mathjax in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-mathjax-in-question-titles)

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of ways to accelerate the convergence of a given sequence or series. A common tool in the context of alternating series is the [Euler transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration#Euler%27s_transform), which states that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{\Delta^n a}{2^{n+1}},
$$
where
$$
\Delta^n a = \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^n \binom{n}{k} a_{n-k}.
$$

To apply that to your approach, we would take
$$
a_n = 
\frac{1}{n}e^{\frac{n^{2}}{2}}\text{erfc}\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}\right).
$$

Using [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/) we can implement this as follows:

```
n,k = var('n,k')
a(n) = exp(n^2/2)*erfc(n/sqrt(2))/n
def fd(n):
  return sum([(-1)^k * binomial(n,k)*a(n-k) for k in range(n)])
sum_result = N(1 - sqrt(2*pi) * sum([(-1)^n * fd(n)/2^(n+1) for n in range(1,50)]))
```

We can also work out the integral numerically:

```
int_result = numerical_integral(exp(-x^2/2)*log(1+exp(x)), -10,10)
```

Given that $\log(1+e^x) \sim x$ for large $x$, it's pretty easy to show should be within machine precision of the improper integral.

You can see how well this worked [in this Sage Cell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=yafimo). There we see that

```
sum_result = 2.02049074000466
int_result = (2.020490740004666, 2.2431953213344902e-14)
```

Note that the integral result includes an error estimate and the sum result is quite close.

Of course, the numerical check rather begs the question - if numerical computation of the integral is your main objective, why not just use numerical integration techniques in the first place?